# Watchdog in python / subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm looking to execute an application that then binds to a defined port if successful, and then poll it over http, if it fails, restart it (pretty much a single-process simple watchdog). Looking at [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess), but a bit unsure as to how to continue. Can anyone point me on a path or something?

The process has no stdin, no stdout, and no stderr (all can be discarded). Just pretty much a loop that checks if it responds (via urllib/Requests?) then sleep 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to execute an application

subprocess module........................

http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module